Moving beltline for Rohloff conversion
After my Shimano Nexus 8 IGH broke prematurely, I've been thinking of converting to a Rohloff, to salvage a mostly new bike (Cube Travel Pro).
The Shimano Nexus 8 runs with a beltline (chainline for Gates belt) of 43.7 mm, but Rohloff's standard beltline is 55 mm. There is a Rohloff Slim Splined Lock-ring Carrier (8540SL) that brings it down to 53 mm, but that seems out of stock everywhere I looked. This means I need to shift the beltline in the front by at least 9.3 mm. Is this possible?
I've never done such conversions, but ~10 mm seems like a lot to me! There was a similar question a few years ago, but it was only a few mm. Perhaps the best way to do this is with a wider bottom bracket, or eventually with spacers? The bicycle has an eccentric bottom bracket to adjust the belt tension, but I guess it is possible to fit any normal bottom bracket in it. Or is it better to adjust the chainring position? I have not seen Gates chainrings with spacers.
There are prebuilt bicycles with Gates and Rohloff, so there must be a way, but somehow it is not obvious to me.

It's possible to adjust the chainring position: I had mine +5mm with chainring spacers. But 10mm may give clearance problems with the crank arm.
The neatest way to do it might be with a modular crank system. A few manufacturers (Middleburn, etc) produce the arms, spiders and spindles as parts you select to get the required configuration for your beltline, using modern external bearings. You can obviously do something similar with a traditional square taper bottom bracket.
At the rear end, many of the gates sprockets are offset and give a different belt line when flipped. This may not help you as it probably doesn't apply to rolhoff - but do check.
A combination of techniques (chainring spacing, bottom bracket spacers) could be used to get the fit correct with what you already have, with some compromise. Don't compromise the straightness of the belt though!

Thanks, I'll look into modular cranks. I read in the Gates technical manual that the BB Thun Zumba GBL 550 is the compatible part for a Rohloff beltline, which can be used with my S150 crank. Sadly, this part appears to be available nowhere outside the Gates manual. Another option is the Gates S550 crankset (eye-watering expensive). In any case, it appears I was too naive to expect to use the same crankset because the gears are so different (nexus gear 1 = Rohloff gear 6). Mostly likely I need more teeth.

One issue with the S150 crank is that you can only mount the front pulley/sprocket/"beltring" to the inside of the spider, So even with spacers, you can only make the beltline smaller. Can you measure the axle length of your current bottom bracket? There probably also are other bottom brackets than the Thun Zumba with the correct length.

Oh yes! the gates chainset on that bike doesn't give you many options, though it fits onto a square taper bottom bracket so at least you could change the bb to one with a 20mm longer spindle--if that is realistically an option, it depends on the starting point. Changing the whole chainset will give you the most options, but at the biggest outlay
